# Can I use std::next on user defined class

Tags: c++, iterator

If I have a user-defined class :

```
class MyColl {
     int *data ;
     public :
     class Itr {
              int operator*() {}
              void operator++()
              bool operator != (const Itr &oth)
     } ;
     Itr begin() {}
     Itr end() {}
} ;
```

Can I use `std::next` on objects of `MyColl`
If yes, then what needs to be done

Comment: You can use `std::next` on any class that properly implements an iterator. `MyColl` is not an iterator; I suspect you are asking about `Itr` that iterates over objects of `MyColl`.

Comment: I have edited my class definition so that `MyColl` supports the required iterator protocol

Comment: I assumed as much when you asked the question. The answer is the same: `std::next()` will work just fine on any properly implemented _iterator_ class. Have fun now! :O)

Comment: I am missing something because I am getting following error `error: no type named ‘difference_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<MyColl::Itr>`

Comment: @user3282758 That is because you haven't defined any traits for `MyColl::Itr` to describe its iterator capabilities.  You need to either 1) declare the appropriate trait types (`difference_type`, `value_type`, etc) directly in `MyColl::Itr` itself, or 2) you need to declare a specialization of [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) for `MyColl::Itr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// How to implement a forward iterator for your collection class

template <typename T>
class MyCollection
{
public:

  struct MyCollectionIterator
  {
    // These five typedefs tell other things about your iterator 
    
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type        = T;
    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer           = T*;
    using reference         = T&;
    
    explicit MyCollectionIterator( ... ) ... {}
    
    // These five methods implement the minimum required behavior of a forward iterator
    
    reference  operator *  () const {...}
    iterator & operator ++ ()       {...}
    iterator   operator ++ (int)    {...}
    
    bool operator == ( iterator that ) {...}
    bool operator != ( iterator that ) {...}
  };
  
  MyCollectionIterator begin() { return MyCollectionIterator(...); }
  MyCollectionIterator end()   { return MyCollectionIterator(...); }
};
```

There are other iterator types beyond a forward iterator. If possible, you should implement the most capable iterator type you can: if not random access, then bidirectional, and if not bidirectional, then forward.

Iterators have been an increasingly frightening thing to look at in C++ ([see docs here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)), but the basic idea is simply a class that knows how to pretend to be a pointer sufficient to access your collection’s data. To do that it must provide certain kinds of information and capabilities.

That little table of iterator types in the linked docs will help you when adding the required functionality to your iterator class.

Comment: It will be much easier to use `boost::iterator_facade` instead of manually implementing all those numerous member functions.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use std::next on user defined class

You can use `std::next` with any class that is an iterator.

> Can I use std::next on objects of MyColl

No, because `MyColl` is not an iterator.

You also cannot use it with `MyColl::Itr`, because that isn't an iterator either.

> I am missing something because I am getting following error `error: no type named ‘difference_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<MyColl::Itr>`

The error message tells you what you're missing. You're missing `std::iterator_traits<MyColl::Itr>::difference_type`. Without it, `MyColl::Itr` is not an iterator. More generally, the class must satisfy all requirements of the `iterator` concept.

Comment: This doesn’t really explain what OP needs to do to make `Itr` a proper iterator — or more specifically, how to fix the problem with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my `Itr` class must define the following :

```
using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
using value_type = int;
using pointer = value_type*;
using reference = value_type&;
```

If I must support the `std::prev` function also then `Itr` must define prefix operator-- and `iterator_category` must be `std::random_access_iterator_tag`

Comment: "*If I must support the `std::prev` function also then ...`iterator_category` must be `std::random_access_iterator_tag`*" - `std::prev` requires bi-directional iterators (random-access iterators are also bi-directional iterators). Don't use `random_access_iterator_tag` unless your iterators are truly random-access (yours are not).  For an iterator that simply goes back and forth via `++`/`--` operators, you need to use `bidirectional_iterator_tag` instead. To support random access, your iterator class would need to implement even more operators: `+`/`+=`, `-`/`-=`, `[]`, `<`/`<=`, and `>`/`>=`